# QML ListView - Change highlight behavior when it reach a certain point

Tags: listview, qml

I want to change highlight behavior when the highlight reach the certain point:

- When the highlight is on top of the list, I want the highlight to move
- But, when the highlight is in the middle of screen, I want the list to move up

Here is the code for now

```
ListView {
    id: collectionAxis

    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        topMargin: vpx(150)
        bottomMargin: vpx(150)
    }

    model: 100
    delegate: collectionAxisDelegate

    spacing: vpx(20)

    highlight: Rectangle {

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        width: vpx(20)
        height: vpx(20)
    }
}
```

[I hope this help clear up what I meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySZkF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are the properties you're interested in setting:

```
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0
        preferredHighlightEnd: height / 2
```

This will mean that when the highlighted is in the top half of the ListView it will not move the ListView, whereas if it is in the bottom half it will cause the ListView to push up so that the highlighted item moves back to the center.

Below is an example where you can click to change the currently highlighted item. After that, you can use another click or use the up and down keys to change the highlighted item.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page
    ListView {
        id: collectionAxis
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            topMargin: vpx(150)
            bottomMargin: vpx(150)
        }
        model: 100
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: vpx(30)
            height: vpx(20)
            text: index
            padding: 0
            onClicked: {
                ListView.view.currentIndex = index;
                ListView.view.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
        spacing: vpx(20)
        highlight: Rectangle {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: vpx(20)
            height: vpx(20)
            color: "#ccf"
        }
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0
        preferredHighlightEnd: height / 2
    }
    function vpx(n) { return n; }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightRangeMode-prop